# Hierarchical Indexing in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I'm working with data with hierarchical indices:

[Public CDC Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qccPD.png)

The goal is to have those hierarchical indices represented in a pandas dataframe and grouped.

This is as close as I've gotten

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/demo/tables/health-insurance/time-series/acs/hic04_acs.xlsx"
ins_data = pd.read_excel(url, header=[3,4])
ins_data = ins_data.set_index(['Nation/State'])
```

But with this code, the index does not group, and when I try to add multiple indexes, I get an error.

I was looking at this website https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/hierarchical-indexing-multiple-indexing-python-pandas/ because it looks exactly like what I'm trying to do, but I was not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a clean indexed dataframe:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(url, skiprows=3, skipfooter=5,
                   index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1])
df = df.rename_axis(columns=["Year", "Variable"],
                    index=["Nation/State", "Coverage"])
```

```py
>>> df.index
MultiIndex([('United States',             'Total'),
            ('United States',      'Any coverage'),
            ('United States',         'Uninsured'),
            ...
            (      'Wyoming',            'Public'),
            (      'Wyoming',        '..Medicaid'),
            (      'Wyoming',        '..Medicare')],
           names=['Nation/State', 'Coverage'], length=571)

>>> df.columns
MultiIndex([(2019,          'Estimate'),
            (2019,   'Margin of error'),
            (2019,           'Percent'),
            ...
            (2008,   'Margin of error'),
            (2008,           'Percent'),
            (2008, 'Margin of error.1')],
           names=['Year', 'Variable'])

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 571 entries, ('United States', 'Total') to ('Wyoming', '..Medicare')
Data columns (total 48 columns):
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                     --------------  -----
 0   (2019, Estimate)           571 non-null    int64
 1   (2019, Margin of error)    571 non-null    object
 2   (2019, Percent)            571 non-null    float64
 ...
 45  (2008, Margin of error)    571 non-null    object
 46  (2008, Percent)            571 non-null    float64
 47  (2008, Margin of error.1)  571 non-null    object
dtypes: float64(12), int64(12), object(24)
memory usage: 218.7+ KB
```

Comment: When I run this, I get "ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2"
on this line "index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1])"

Comment: I found this thread with the same problem https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15133, but not sure how to fix

Comment: What is your version of Pandas (`pd.__version__`)?